# Node.js - Merging various PDFs that contains input fields with data into a single PDF returns blank input fields in the merged PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm

I am trying to write a program in which my Node.js code reads all the PDFs present in a particular folder and combines all those individual PDFs present in the folder into a merged PDF.

The code works fine for the PDFs that don't contain input fields and everything is working as expected. But the problem arises when a PDF contains input fields. The individual PDFs show the data filled into the input fields but while merging the individual PDFs, the merged PDF makes the input fields blank.

I am using the `pdf-lib` npm module to merge the PDFs. Can anyone help me out on this?